# How do I add a kernel boot parameter?

Tags: kernel, grub2

I need to add the boot parameter `foo=bar` to my kernel. How can I do this once for testing, and permanently if testing was a success?

Answer (score 351, accepted):

### To temporarily add a boot parameter to a kernel

1. Start your system and wait for the GRUB menu to show (if you don't see a GRUB menu, press and hold the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key right after starting the system).
2. Now highlight the kernel you want to use, and press the <kbd>e</kbd> key. You should be able to see and edit the commands associated with the highlighted kernel.
3. Go down to the line starting with `linux` and add your parameter `foo=bar` to its end.
4. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to boot.

### To make this change permanent

1. From a terminal (or after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) run:

   ```
    gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   (or use `sudo nano` if `gksudo` or `gedit` are not available) and enter your password.
2. Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and append `foo=bar` to its end. For example:

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash foo=bar"
   ```

   Save the file and close the editor.
3. Finally, start a terminal and run:

   ```
    sudo update-grub
   ```

   to update GRUB's configuration file (you probably need to enter your password).

On the next reboot, the kernel should be started with the boot parameter. To permanently remove it, simply remove the parameter from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and run `sudo update-grub` again.

To verify your changes, you can see exactly what parameters your kernel booted with by executing `cat /proc/cmdline`.

[Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions).

Comment: Shift doesn’t work for me. I used Esc instead. Had to be careful not to hold it too long or it would blow right through GRUB

Comment: `gksudo` is no longer in Ubuntu.  Use `pkexec` instead.

Comment: Shift doesn't work when booting in UEFI mode, apparently. There, you have to press Esc repeatedly, but stop once you get to the GRUB menu or it'll drop to the GRUB shell.

Comment: also see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65296/272812) for a `sed` command to get the variable

Comment: For Archlinux, the command to update grub is `grub-mkconfig -o /path/to/grub.cfg`. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/kernel_parameters#GRUB

Answer (score 17):

**To add any kernel option:**

- **for a liveCD session:** follow [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD.27s_Default_Boot_Options)
- **for an Existing Installation:** use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s `Add a kernel option` or `Edit GRUB configuration file` options.

[image]

See also [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_boot_options_Permanently_for_an_Existing_Installation).

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, you may also use the handy [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
gksu grub-customizer &
```

Just open a boot entry, and edit its kernel parameters as highlighted in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]